# ASP.NET MVC 3 Routing With No Specific Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, seo

I have a really interesting case:

I have a site where this is already working

- http://mysite.com/
- http://mysite.com/browse/mens
- http://mysite.com/product/1/cooltshirt

But I'd also like these urls to work as well

- http://mysite.com/farm
- http://mysite.com/farm/browse/mens
- http://mysite.com/farm/product/1/cooltshirt

**the farm part is fake, it doesn't do anything except to exist for SEO, there is no corresponding controller or action associated with it**

Essentially, I have a ton of routes already, but I'd also like the site to behave exactly the same if "farm" is appended after the "mysite" the hostname. So it's kind of like a subdirectory behaving exactly like going on the main site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a route with constraint. Make sure it's above the default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Farm", // Route name
    "farm/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"} // Parameter defaults
);
```

It just makes sure URLs starting with "farm" gets their controller name from 2nd segment and action name from the 3rd segment.

Comment: Also, remember to register this route after the first if dont you want your outgoing URLs to have farms

Comment: It took me a while to notice that the order did matter.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a FarmController, you can just have them rout to your farmcontroller

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Farm", // Route name
    "Farm/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Farm", action = "Index"} // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't say it earlier, but the farm part is just a fake seo friendly text. There's no respective controller.

Comment: then you could use the query string the get it